# Как проигнорировать свойство класса в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Пишу программу в стиле `MVVM`.
Делаю привязку

```
List<People> PeopleList = new List<People>();
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

`DataGrid` автоматически генерирует поля на основе открытых свойств класса `People`.
Так вот мне нужно, чтоб определённые свойства класса `People` не генерировались в `DataGrid`. Может надо применить к свойству кокой-то атрибут типа `[XmlIgnore]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте событие [`DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn.aspx). Можете так-же использовать схожий по назначению атрибут [`Browsable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) или написать для этого свой атрибут.

```
// class People
[Browsable(false)]
public int MyProperty { ... }

// event AutoGeneratingColumn
void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).IsBrowsable == false)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно еще сделать `Generate Columns` в `DataGrid`, а затем в `Edit Property-Bound Columns` снять нужные галочки.